# How do I read specification for wheels in Audi?

Tags: tires, wheels, audi

I would like to change wheels in my car and I need to understand first what are the most suitable for it. But I dont get why there are a few rows for it?

[image]

1. Can I choose anyone from the above list? For example, if I want rims with 19 inch, there is only one option for that, right?
2. What that icons with people and bags means?

Comment: The "icons of people and bags" means the number of people and bags or suitcases or baggage. The open book with the exclamation mark means read the owners manual - as there will be more detailed information in there. This sticker is just a summary.

Comment: The one at the bottom is a much narrower tyre, is that for a 'space saver' spare wheel? As said above, after reading the handbook, this is just a reminder of what *pressures* to use for a particular combination of tyre and loading. Note that if you replace the wheels, it may affect the cost or validity of the vehicle insurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get to where you're going from this chart. This chart ONLY tells you the tire pressures for the options given from the factory. The sizes you're seeing there are specific to the tire sizes, not the rim sizes. It shows the different tire options which could have come from the factory.

So, yes, there was a 19" option from the factory, but that is the only information you know. This means *some kind of 19" rim will fit on your Audi.* You don't know (at least from this chart) what the dimensions of the rim was which supported the tire.

There are four main size components to a rim: **diameter; width; offset; bolt pattern**. Your best bet to find what are the rim sizes you can use is to do one of three things.

- **Visit a tire/wheel store online which has a calculator for you.** A lot of them will have a vehicle picker where you can input your car and it will show you what they have available which will fit your vehicle. There's many online I've seen before, so there shouldn't be an issue shopping around. You should also be able to get the correct sizes for your vehicle and go shopping from there.
- **Find stock rims for the vehicle which are 19".** You can go to the dealership to do this or find some online at eBay or some other place like that.
- **Go to a local tire/wheel shop.** They'll be able to fit your car without issue.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if I understand it well. Above diagram means only what pressure in tires is needed for the wheels which are in the specific car from the factory. There is 7 options, and mine is one of them, right? (225/50 R17 947, I got it from the tire is currently installed). So it doesnt mean that, If I want to have 19 inch then I have to change to 6th option, right? That info is possible to get using one of options you posted. And one more question. What is the maximum width of tire I can put in my car?

Comment: The chart is ONLY for tire pressures, not for rim sizes. The TIRE SIZES specified on the chart are there because there were multiple TIRE sizes available for your vehicle. Rather than specifying only the tire size which came on your car when purchased new, they provide the pressures for all of them so they only have to create one sticker. The sixth option is ONE of the tire sizes. Because it was a stock option, you can be assured this tire size will fit on your vehicle, with the proper wheel size.

Comment: @bart Just visit the Audi dealership, you'll know the exact rim specs and you can install any compatible tire based on your suspension setup. If you share the year, variant and version of your audi, I will find out from a dealer here.

Comment: @NumairAidroos Audi A5 8T 2015

Comment: Could you write it using specificstion like 225/50 R19?;)

Comment: @bart 19 inch diameter, 9 inch width. 112x5 pcd. Center bore 66.5 mm. Use the same wheel lug nuts.

Comment: 255/35/R19 tires rated Y or above.

Comment: For 225/50/R19, you can opt for 19x8J, standard ET45 wheels. 255 35 R19 use 19x9J aka ET33. You have the offset and pcd from above which is standard across all rims for your Audi A5.